# How can I initialize wpdb class in a php file?

Tags: wordpress

i am new in wordpress. i want to run a sql from a php file and this file is calling from a plugin file. my plugin file code is:

```
if (confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Delete?')){ 
window.location.href = '../wp-content/plugins/delete_data.php?id=<?php echo $db_data['dynamicmenu_id']; ?>';
} else{
}
```

and this code is running from script.
 my delete_data.php file code is given below:

```
dlt_opt();
function dlt_opt(){
    global $wpdb;
    var_dump($wpdb);
    $dlt_id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."dynamicmenu WHERE dynamicmenu_id=".$dlt_id ) );
}
```

but in delete_data.php is creating error because it is not finding $wpdb and is null. So wpdb is not initializing and it can't find wpdb class. how can i add wpdb class? 
Error message is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ...\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\delete_data.php on line 7
```

Need help

Comment: add the file wp-load.php,

for example:

require_once('../../wp-load.php');

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55625/how-to-initialize-wpdb/257390#257390

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-load.php');

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer. I need to include wp-load.php in that file.

```
require_once('../../wp-load.php');
```

although it's not a good practice to delete like this.