# Wordpress wp_set_object_terms SQL errors

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm creating relationships on post types using this funciton:

```
private function setObjectTerms($last_insert_id){

      //INSERT course_type/RELATIONSHIP
      wp_set_object_terms($last_insert_id,$this->course_type,'course-type'); 

  }
```

Above, the course type can be 'free', or 'paid', and the $last_insert_id is just a number..

Anyway I keep getting this error, and have no idea why:

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'AS tr INNER JOIN AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id =
>   tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tr.ob' at line 1]
>
> SELECT tr.term_taxonomy_id
>   FROM AS tr INNER JOIN AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id =
>   tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tr.object_id IN (15534) AND tt.taxonomy IN
>   ('course-type')

The strange thing is I been using this same function, and it has worked. I just don't get why the SQL produced is incorrect. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

```
$wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991556/use-wp-query-after-changing-database-via-new-wpdb) fellow battlers

Answer (score 1):

The `wp_term_taxonomy` and `wp_term_relationships` table names are missing from this failed query, so, unsurprisingly, MySQL gags on it.

Internally in WordPress, the `global $wpdb` object furnishes those table names to the function that's building the query. If it has empty strings for the table names, it hasn't (yet) been initialized.

You may not have set up WordPress correctly before calling this function.

See this:  [How can I initialize wpdb class in a php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804589/how-can-i-initialize-wpdb-class-in-a-php-file)

Comment: thanks for the answer..I get where you're coming from, I've checked how my wpdb class is initialized, and it is just like the solution of that question. Really stumped, because the exact same function works when implemented from a different class...I can't see any differences with the working class and this one...i guess I'll sleep on it